# Dynamic query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I had big query in a stored procedure. In single SQL query can't execute the total code. So I have been used two dynamic queries. When I am trying to print or execute in the middle of the code some lines are missing. I am confused where should I need to start the new `Query1` exactly or any other way that I can execute whole query:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[spGetRPTTot]
    (//parameters
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sqlQuery = ' //code '

    DECLARE @sqlQuery1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sqlQuery1 = ' //code '

    PRINT (@sqlQuery + @sqlQuery1)
    EXECUTE (@sqlQuery + @sqlQuery1)
END
GO
```

Comment: You sure you are using MySQL? Because this SQL statement isn't MySQL compatible. `CREATE Proc`, brackets ( `[ ]` ), `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `print` and `execute` are SQL-server compatible SQL and not MySQL SQL with what you have tagged this question. .So i've changed the tag from MySQL into SQL-server

Comment: that seems to be working to print out the lines just fine for me, but if you are building out multiple lines in each SQL query you need to post all the code as something in your code that builds out each line may be incorrect causing missing data.  Plus do you have 2 different queries?  Or are you combining 2 parts of a single query?  The first part is select, and the second is the where clause?

Comment: I am combining 2 parts of a single query. No problem in the code when I am executing in Server as a single query it executes perfectly .

Comment: You can't pass an expression to your `EXECUTE` command, you need to concatenate the values first and pass them as a single value.

Comment: Can you please show me example how to concatenate and pass single value

Comment: `set @variable = @variable + @variable2`, but there doesn't seem to be any reason to have 2 variables here.

Comment: To be honest, though, this seems like this particular SP is wide open to SQL injection. We don't have a non-redacted version to confirm this, but I think you'd be better using a parametrised query using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: James Z, why not make an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/  
SET @SQLString =  
     N'SELECT BusinessEntityID, NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, LoginID  
   FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee   
   WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@BusinessEntityID tinyint';  
/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 197;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                  @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;  
/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */  
SET @IntVariable = 109;  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  
                  @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```